# Extruding filled curve converted to mesh

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves, extrude

Ive been tracing multiple characters with curves, filling, converting to mesh, and extruding to achieve a 3D representation. However, this one character does not work.
[image]

Selecting upwards facing normals on faces on other objects does not highlight the faces on this mesh, but works for all others created with this process and allows me to extrude upwards. Also, it seems like there are a crazy amount of faces generated on top.
Is there a way to fix this generated mesh that would easily allow me to extrude this up? Or an alternate method to achieve this?
I tried the decimate option in clean up mesh and it didn't seem to work.

Thanks!

Comment: When you tried decimate, did you set it to _planar_?

Comment: I'm not sure what's your problem but to simplify this kind of mesh you can select all and press X > Limited Dissolve